# How to repeat row headers in each row of each column of a page in word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table in a page in a Word document. The page has several columns and the table is spanned across these columns.

I want the first row to appear at the top of each column. How can I achieve this?

A partial view of the table, I am working with, is in the following link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the header row(s) and set them to repeat. It works for multi-column tables as well as multi-page tables.

For example, in Word 2010, select the header rows, then in the Table Tools->Layout tab, click Repeat Header Rows.